# Timespan for default /admin/refresh in SDL

Tags: sdl-tridion

There are following ways from which we can refresh the web application settings:

1. Appending /admin/refresh at the end of web application url
2. Restarting the hosted site on IIS
3. Manually creating an admin controller which also be used for same purpose by calling Localization.Refresh().

Apart from above three, is there any other way we could refresh the settings..or any default time after which these gets cleared automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin refresh is not a automatic or time bound process. We have to manually hit the URL with /admin/refresh in it. To make this a automated process, you can create a scheduled task on your web server, which will Invoke the Site URL with /admin/refresh in timely manner, say every 12 hrs.

You can use PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest Method for this.